# Reverse the order of the rows for every 'id' in data in R

Tags: r, dataframe, group-by

I'm using R and stuck at the following problem.
I have a data called `data`.
`data` has columns including `id` and `date`.
`id` stands for personal id number. Within each `id` , there are several rows arranged by `date` . However, the `date` is ordered reversely, so I want to reverse the rows again. I don't know how to do it. I tried to do it using `group_by(id)`

Comment: `group_by(id) %>% arrange(date)`?

Comment: It printed out that there's no function `%>%`. Which library should I import?

Comment: Oh, I assume you are already using dplyr when you use "group_by". Just install and load the library "tidyverse". It is quite valuable for data wrangling work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an dplyr example:

```
library(tidyverse)
data <- tibble(id = rep(letters[1:3], each=3),
                   date = rep(as.Date(c("2022-07-01", "2022-06-25", "2022-05-15")), 3))

data %>% arrange(id, date)

# A tibble: 9 x 2
  id    date      
  <chr> <date>    
1 a     2022-05-15
2 a     2022-06-25
3 a     2022-07-01
4 b     2022-05-15
5 b     2022-06-25
6 b     2022-07-01
7 c     2022-05-15
8 c     2022-06-25
9 c     2022-07-01
```

Base solution without using `dplyr`

```
data[order(data$id, data$date),]
```

Comment: I used the solution without using `dplyr` and it worked!